# java script onkeypress event (search bar without button)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

im using this javascript to have an event on my onkeypress

```
function myFunction() {
   if (window.event || window.event.keyCode == 13) {   
      changeSource();
   } 
}

function changeSource(){
   document.getElementById("frame1").src="Log-In.aspx";
   window.alert("wow");
}
```

this is where i will use my onkeypress event

```
<input id= "Text1" placeholder="Search here..." type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()"/>
```

and this is the iframe that i want the event to be change

```
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" name="page" src="about:blank" ></iframe>
```

the problem is i can't change the src in my  iframe but the event is triggering

Comment: Maybe `document.getElementById('frame1').contentWindow.location.href = 'Log-in.aspx';` would do the trick.

Comment: what browser are you using? It works fine at my place..

Comment: im using google chrome, firefox and opera

i  have now fix the problem (window.event || window.event.keyCode == 13) i change the OR to AND thanks for the comments guys i appreciate it a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use setAttribute to change the attribute value.

```
document.getElementById("frame1").setAttribute('src',"Log-In.aspx");
```